# Don't get ControlsFX repo to compile

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I cannot compile the *ControlsFX* repo which I cloned from Github. It does not work because there are absolute paths in the required libraries (the ones with user "Eugene") that do not exist on my machine.

[image]

Comment: that's a shame. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where did you clone it from? GitHub? That's not the official repo for ControlsFX.

Comment: Yes from Github.

Comment: FXExperience is a better choice. Solved now. Thanks to Mr Pereda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are cloning ControlsFX from GitHub, you are cloning a fork, but not the official repo.

It seems [this fork](https://github.com/jinghai/controlsfx) has some hardcoded paths in the `.classpath` file, similar to those you posted in the screenshot.

If this is your source:

- This repo is a fork, not the official repo
- It hasn't been updated since more than four years
- You should check for a more trustable source

The official repo is in BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx

**EDIT**

If you just want to use ControlsFX as a dependency in your project, you don't need to clone or build the project from the scratch, you can just add it as a dependency.

There are several ways to do it, based on how you build your project.

- With ant, adding manually your dependencies, you can download the jar from [FXExperience](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) for instance, but it is better if you do it directly from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.controlsfx%22%20AND%20a%3A%22controlsfx%22). Select the required version (8.40.14 for Java 8 or 9.0.0 for Java 9), and download the [jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/controlsfx/controlsfx/8.40.14/).
- With Maven or Gradle, you can just include the dependency:

Maven:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
    <version>8.40.14</version>
 </dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
 compile 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.14'
```

Comment: José, what about the JAR from FXExperience? Would you also recommend?

Comment: Thank you José, great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since [2018-12-29](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/commits/ffbe694287a11cabd8bded01bdd3177d2b833f99) ControlsFX has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx)